# How to get multi-dimenstional primitive array class in kotlin?

Tags: java, arrays, json, kotlin, gson

in Java I have been using gson to parse a json like this `[[1.2, 4.1], [3.4, 4.4]]` into a java primitive multi-array `double[][]`

The code looks like this (and works fine) :

```
String json = "[[1.2, 4.1], [3.4, 4.4]]"
double[][] variable = new Gson().fromJson(json, double[][].class);
```

Is there a way to get the `double[][].class` in kotlin ?
Is `double[][] variable;` can be substitute in kotlin ?

Edit :

My goal is to achieve the same behavior with gson in kotlin. I have thousand of doubles arrays to parse.

I would like to do something like this in kotlin :

```
val json = "[[1.1, 1.2], [2.1, 2.2, 2.3], [3.1, 3.2]"
val variable:Double[][] = Gson().fromJson(json, Double[][]::class.java)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer to the Gson problem

For the class type of your use case use `Array<DoubleArray>::class.java)`

### Some additional Words on Multidimensional Arrays

Simply wrap `arrayOf` into another `arrayOf` or `doubleArrayOf` (less Boxing overhead) to get something like `Array<DoubleArray>`:

```
val doubles : Array<DoubleArray>  = arrayOf(doubleArrayOf(1.2), doubleArrayOf(2.3))
```

It's also possible to nest multiple Array initializers with the following `constructor`:

```
public inline constructor(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)
```

A call can look like this:

```
val doubles2: Array<DoubleArray> = Array(2) { i ->
    DoubleArray(2) { j ->
        j + 1 * (i + 1).toDouble()
    }
}
//[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]]
```

Comment: You can do   Array<DoubleArray>::class.java

Answer (score 1):

In the future, you can try using the Kotlin converter.  I took your code and ran it through the converter and got the following working code which agrees with the answer given.

```
internal var json = "[[1.2, 4.1], [3.4, 4.4]]"
internal var variable = Gson().fromJson(json, Array<DoubleArray>::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mix `arrayOf` and `doubleArrayOf` for that case.

```
arrayOf(
    doubleArrayOf(1.2, 4.1)
    doubleArrayOf(3.4, 4.4)
)
```